# Как правильно переопределить метод

Tags: javascript

У меня есть класс Point в котором существует метод  showPoints() для вывода информации о точке с координатами и установкой координаты x и y. Создать второстепенный класс Graphicpoint. В этом классе добавляются новые данные: цвет точки, функция вывода координат точки.Я сделал так , но у меня возникла проблема с наследованием. В коде видно, что я создаю метод в классе предка в котором добавляю значение координат в массив. Но когда я переопределяю метод в классе graphicPoint то этот метод просто не видит эту переменную. Получается когда мы переопределяем метод , переменные которые были там объявлены не передаются в метод другого класса? Как тогда будет правильно поступить, можно ли к примеру тогда объявить эту переменную в конструкторе класса Point

```js
class Point{
  constructor(x,y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  showPoints(){
    let resultArr = [];
    resultArr.push(this.x);
    resultArr.push(this.y);
    return resultArr;
  }

  set cordinateX(number){
    this.x = number;
  }

  set cordinateY(number){
    this.y = number;
  }

}

class GraphicPoint extends Point{
    constructor(x,y,color){
      super(x,y);
      this.color = color;
    }
    showPoints(){
    super.showPoints();
    resultArr.push(this.color);
    return resultArr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как пример, можно сделать вот так:

```js
class Point {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  getPoints() {
    return [this.x, this.y];
  }
}

class GraphicPoint extends Point {
  constructor(x, y, color) {
    super(x, y);
    this.color = color;
  }

  getPoints() {
    return [...super.getPoints(), this.color];
  }
}

var gp = new GraphicPoint(1, 3, 'red');

console.log(gp.getPoints());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
showPoints(){
  let resultArr = [];
  resultArr.push(this.x);
  resultArr.push(this.y);
  return resultArr;
}
```

Здесь `resultArr` локальная переменная внутри `Point.showPoints`, о которой снаружи этого метода никому ничего не известно.

```js
class Point {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  showPoints() {
    let resultArr = [];
    resultArr.push(this.x);
    resultArr.push(this.y);
    return resultArr;
  }

  set cordinateX(number) {
    this.x = number;
  }

  set cordinateY(number) {
    this.y = number;
  }

}

class GraphicPoint extends Point {
  constructor(x, y, color) {
    super(x, y);
    this.color = color;
  }
  showPoints() {
    var resultArr = super.showPoints(); // !!!
    resultArr.push(this.color);
    return resultArr;
  }
}

var gp = new GraphicPoint(123, 456, "green");
console.log(gp.showPoints());
```